# Does anyone know where can I find DockerFIle for aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.1.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild, docker-image

I am looking for dockerFile for `aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.1.0` which used to be available on GitHub earlier but not anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find the `aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.1.0`.

> Release updated standard 2.0 image @minethai minethai released this on
>   Jun 26 · 15 commits to master since this release

You can download the zip folder form [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/archive/1.11.0.zip).

Changes:

**Updated minor versions for node8, node10, powershell, and gradle 5**

```
# Copyright 2017-2017 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# A copy of the License is located at
#
#    http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
#
# or in the "license" file accompanying this file.
# This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
#

FROM ubuntu:14.04.5

ENV DOCKER_BUCKET="download.docker.com" \
    DOCKER_VERSION="17.09.0-ce" \
    DOCKER_CHANNEL="stable" \
    DOCKER_SHA256="a9e90a73c3cdfbf238f148e1ec0eaff5eb181f92f35bdd938fd7dab18e1c4647" \
    DIND_COMMIT="3b5fac462d21ca164b3778647420016315289034" \
    DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION="1.21.2" \
    GITVERSION_VERSION="3.6.5"

# Install git, SSH, and other utilities
RUN set -ex \
    && echo 'Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99use-gzip-compression \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt install -y apt-transport-https \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
    && echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install software-properties-common -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install git=1:2.* -y --no-install-recommends \
    && git version \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-client=1:6.6* \
    && mkdir ~/.ssh \
    && touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa -H bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       wget=1.15-* python=2.7.* python2.7-dev=2.7.* fakeroot=1.20-* ca-certificates \
       tar=1.27.* gzip=1.6-* zip=3.0-* autoconf=2.69-* automake=1:1.14.* \
       bzip2=1.0.* file=1:5.14-* g++=4:4.8.* gcc=4:4.8.* imagemagick=8:6.7.* \
       libbz2-dev=1.0.* libc6-dev=2.19-* libcurl4-openssl-dev=7.35.* libdb-dev=1:5.3.* \
       libevent-dev=2.0.* libffi-dev=3.1~* libgeoip-dev=1.6.* libglib2.0-dev=2.40.* \
       libjpeg-dev=8c-* libkrb5-dev=1.12+* liblzma-dev=5.1.* \
       libmagickcore-dev=8:6.7.* libmagickwand-dev=8:6.7.* libmysqlclient-dev=5.5.* \
       libncurses5-dev=5.9+* libpng12-dev=1.2.* libpq-dev=9.3.* libreadline-dev=6.3-* \
       libsqlite3-dev=3.8.* libssl-dev=1.0.* libtool=2.4.* libwebp-dev=0.4.* \
       libxml2-dev=2.9.* libxslt1-dev=1.1.* libyaml-dev=0.1.* make=3.81-* \
       patch=2.7.* xz-utils=5.1.* zlib1g-dev=1:1.2.* unzip=6.0-* curl=7.35.* \
       e2fsprogs=1.42.* iptables=1.4.* xfsprogs=3.1.* xz-utils=5.1.* \
       mono-devel less=458-* groff=1.22.* liberror-perl=0.17-* \
       asciidoc=8.6.* build-essential=11.* bzr=2.6.* cvs=2:1.12.* cvsps=2.1-* docbook-xml=4.5-* docbook-xsl=1.78.* dpkg-dev=1.17.* \
       libdbd-sqlite3-perl=1.40-* libdbi-perl=1.630-* libdpkg-perl=1.17.* libhttp-date-perl=6.02-* \
       libio-pty-perl=1:1.08-* libserf-1-1=1.3.* libsvn-perl=1.8.* libsvn1=1.8.* libtcl8.6=8.6.* libtimedate-perl=2.3000-* \
       libunistring0=0.9.* libxml2-utils=2.9.* libyaml-perl=0.84-* python-bzrlib=2.6.* python-configobj=4.7.* \
       sgml-base=1.26+* sgml-data=2.0.* subversion=1.8.* tcl=8.6.* tcl8.6=8.6.* xml-core=0.13+* xmlto=0.0.* xsltproc=1.1.* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get clean

# Download and set up GitVersion
RUN set -ex \
    && wget "https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases/download/v${GITVERSION_VERSION}/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION}.zip" -O /tmp/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION}.zip \
    && mkdir -p /usr/local/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION} \
    && unzip /tmp/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION}.zip -d /usr/local/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION} \
    && rm /tmp/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION}.zip \
    && echo "mono /usr/local/GitVersion_${GITVERSION_VERSION}/GitVersion.exe \$@" >> /usr/local/bin/gitversion \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitversion

# Install Docker
RUN set -ex \
    && curl -fSL "https://${DOCKER_BUCKET}/linux/static/${DOCKER_CHANNEL}/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" -o docker.tgz \
    && echo "${DOCKER_SHA256} *docker.tgz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar --extract --file docker.tgz --strip-components 1  --directory /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm docker.tgz \
    && docker -v \
# set up subuid/subgid so that "--userns-remap=default" works out-of-the-box
    && addgroup dockremap \
    && useradd -g dockremap dockremap \
    && echo 'dockremap:165536:65536' >> /etc/subuid \
    && echo 'dockremap:165536:65536' >> /etc/subgid \
    && wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/${DIND_COMMIT}/hack/dind" -O /usr/local/bin/dind \
    && curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dind /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
# Ensure docker-compose works
    && docker-compose version

# Install dependencies by all python images equivalent to buildpack-deps:jessie
# on the public repos.

RUN set -ex \
    && wget "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py" -O /tmp/get-pip.py \
    && python /tmp/get-pip.py \
    && pip install awscli==1.* \
    && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

VOLUME /var/lib/docker

COPY dockerd-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENV NODE_VERSION="10.1.0"

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-team
RUN set -ex \
    && for key in \
      94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
      B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
      77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
      56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE \
      71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
      FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
      8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
      C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
      DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
      9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
      93C7E9E91B49E432C2F75674B0A78B0A6C481CF6 \
      114F43EE0176B71C7BC219DD50A3051F888C628D \
      7937DFD2AB06298B2293C3187D33FF9D0246406D \
    ; do \
      gpg --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
      gpg --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
      gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done

RUN set -ex \
    && wget "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -O node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && wget "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" -O SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
        && tar -xzf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
        && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
        && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN npm set unsafe-perm true

CMD [ "node" ]
```

Comment: In addition to what @Adiii said, you can access that specific Dockerfile at https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/unsupported_images/nodejs/10.1.0/Dockerfile. They have been moved to "unsupported_images" directory, since the base image used is EOL (Ubuntu 14.04). Also that node version has a relatively outdated minor version.

Comment: Thanks guys. Exactly what I was looking for. 